# Error Installing Linuux-image-5.15.0-46-generic

Tags: virtualbox

I am not familiar with computer programming terminology.

I was installing Ubuntu in Oracles Virtual Box and towards the end of the installation I get this error:

---

Error Installing Linux-image-5.15.0-46-generic

Installed linux-image-5.15.0-46-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1

---

I click "ok' then:

---

Error while installing packages

An error occurred while installing packages:
E:Sub-process/usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

The following packages are in a broken state:

This may be due to using an old installer image, ort it may be due to a bug in some of the packagees listed above. More details may be found in /var/log/syslog. The installer will try to continue anyway, but may fail at a later point, and will not be able to install or remove other packages (possibly including itself) from the installed system. You should first look for newer versions of your installer image, or failing that report the problem to your distributor.

---

It say installation complete. So I clicked "Restart Now". This is what I get.

---

/dev/sda3: clean, 214055/622592 files, 2361554/2489344 blocks

[ 8.307596] mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)
[ 9.045373] [drm:vmw_host_printf [vmwgfx]] *ERROR* Failed to send host log me message.

---

I deleted the virtual folder, downloaded fresh virtual box and ubuntu, re-tried installing.

Pls. help.

Thank you.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu were you trying to install...?

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS 64 bit

Comment: What Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS are you installing?  64-bit means *amd64*?  *arm64*? *ppc64el*? etc... and then do you mean Desktop or Server.  Please be precise with details.  Did you allocate the required minimum storage for the *unstated* desktop/server version you're using? (desktop requires more space than server does!).

Comment: Thanks Guiverc.

Comment: Your comments made me realize a lot of things.

Comment: First this is the first Ubuntu experience with Ubuntu, Virtual Box. All this started while watching Youtube. Anyway..

Comment: Since it is a Virtual Machine, I realized my host machine may not have extra resources to support 22.04. So I downloaded 20.04.4LTS and I was successful. For now I am happy to try this LTS version..... which I learned was a very stable OS. I will try to install 22 on another machine and will see how it goes. In the mean time. Thanks for you and everyone's help.

Comment: I did try to install U22 for several times. I succeed after adding some VRAM and use a minimal installation (maybe there was a problem with a virtual drive size).

Answer (score 4):

JRey, I had the same issue, after many reinstallations of Ubuntu on my VM I tried to allocate more Memory to the VM (20GB) and my installation was successful

Comment: Wow... Just wow. You're right! I've changed settings from 4 GB to 8 GB and the whole process went smoothly this time. I'd like to see some warning from Ubuntu for that...

Comment: OMG. I was unable to install Xubuntu 22.04 due to error installating linux-image-... with 8GB of ram. I give a try with 32GB and it worked!